# Testing Parent method in Stateless Child component

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme, spy

I have a problem and here is the background:

I have a particular Parent component P which has a stateless child component (A) and A has a stateless child component (B). B is the grandchild of P.

I have a method which is defined in P and is passed to B via props through A. B is a dropdown field and the method is called when an onChange event occurs.

When I tried writing a test to test if the method is called when an onChange event is simulated, i get the following issue: "Expected undefined to equal true"

sample.test.js (Shortened for simplicity)

```
const mockMethod = jest.fn()
const props = {
    method = mockMethod,
    ...
}
const wrapper = (<ChildComponent {...props} />);
const event = {"value": {"region": "APAC"}}
wrapper.find('GrandChildComponent').at(0).simulate("change", event);
expect(mockMethod.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
```

At the very least I want to know why there is a undefined since i declared it above? Also, will my test pass? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Expected undefined to equal true"

```
expect(mockMethod.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
```

Sorry i would put this in comments but i don't have rep for it yet! What is calledOnce?

```
const mockMethod = jest.fn()
```

should the above line have a function in it?